# numeros en express y nodejs (body-parser)

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs, express, ejs

tengo el siguiente problema. Cuando se hace el POST hacia el bakcend(Nodejs) y la informacion pasada es logeada en la consola se muestra el valor de los inputs de type="number" como si fueran strings.

Esto es lo que logea:

```
{ student: 'a',
  term_1: '2',
  term_2: '1',
  term_3: '3' }
```

Lo que necesesitaria es que los valores de term_1, term_2 y term_3 se muestren en valores numericos, no en texto.

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="10" name="term_1">
<input type="number" min="1" max="10" name="term_2">
<input type="number" min="1" max="10" name="term_3">
```

Comment: como envías tus números y como los recibes? puedes hacer un cast  del valor

Comment: Los envio a traves de un formulario con el metodo POST con los inputs que se muestran en el posteo. Y los recibo con `app.get('/login', (req, res) => {console.log(req.body)})`. Que vendria a hacer un cast?

Comment: revisa este [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34502890/ajax-post-sends-numbers-as-string)

Comment: `term_1`, `term_2` y `term_3` corresponden a la etiqueta HTML, ¿por qué no intentarlo de la siguiente manera? `<input type="number" min="1" max="10" value="term_1">`, con esto y con lo que te comenta Teo Villa sería suficiente para que puedas obtener los datos del lado del *back-end*

Comment: esta bien que esperes entero, pero  como toda programacion de backend debes validarlo , esto te lo comento como una recomendacion

Comment: Hola @Teovilla , al recibir podrás intentar `var _term_1 = parseInt(term_1);`